# Google analytics event tracking (gtag) not displaying

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to setup event tracking for google analytics, and I've got the following code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config','UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
</script>

onclick="javascript:gtag('event','Download',{'event_category':'Teacher Guide - Agroforestry','event_label':'Teacher Resource','value':'Teacher Resource'});"
```

It's displaying under **Real-Time > Events** if I click on the link, but it doesn't display under **Behaviour -> Events -> Overview**.

Could someone tell me if I'm missing something, or if I've set it up incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you are using GA free.

If you are seeing the events real time, then you need to wait for at least 24-72 hrs to get the data updated under **Behaviour -> Events -> Overview.**

If you are a GA 360 customer, then you have to wait about 2 hrs to get the data in the reports

Comment: This is a time-wasting UX issue, IMO. I recommend people send feedback to Google that any delay/throttling of data is made known to the end user from within the GA portal/UI if technically possible.